# Using a C# WebBrowser control, can I print the document with different headers on each page?

Tags: c#, html, header, browser, footer

first, when I say header, i dont mean the text in the  tags...
I mean like the header of the page when printing.

So basically what I need is to be able to change the header of certain pages based on what "section" the current page is describing...So it might look something like this

```
**Header for Section 11-33-00**
Section 11-33-00 Text
...
...

<new page>

**header for section 11-33-00**
Section 11-33-00 More text
..
..

<new page>

**header for section 28-30-00
Section 28-30-00 text
..
..
```

As you can see from the example, Pages 1 and 2 both have information for section 11-33-00, so they have the same header. Then on page 3, the header changes.

The default headers when printing have "Page 1 of 3"...this value changes as the pages change, so how does this happen? Is there a way for me to have an array of the different section that the printPreviewDialog will look at, and change the value of the header depending on the current page?

```
for example, instead of these headers:

Page 1 of 3
Page 2 of 3
Page 3 of 3

I would have:

Section 11-22-33
Section 11-22-33
Section 22-33-99
```

?

Or is this completely impossible......

If you have any ideas I would appreciate, cause right now all I can do is hide the headers using this code:

```
string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup";
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true)) {
                if (key != null) {
                    string[] str = new string[] {"One", "Two"};
                    key.SetValue("footer", str);
                    key.SetValue("header", "");

                    web_display.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();

                }
            }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you printing a page that you have control over? If so, I believe you'll find CSS helpful.

Comment: mmm, what do you mean by have control over?

Comment: Is it your web page/content or someone else's?

Answer (score 0):

To get print preview from webbrowser control use

```
webBrowser1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
```

you can get a very good article in code project link 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WBrowser.aspx